# Notation for sequence spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, notation

Let $E$ be finite or countably infinite.

> Is there a simple notation to describe the (Hilbert) space of real, square-summable sequences indexed by $E$?

Effectively, I want the space to be $\mathbb{R}^{\textrm{card}E}$ equipped with the Euclidean inner product whenever $E$ is finite and $\ell^2$ whenever $E$ is countably infinite. However, I'm hoping there is a simpler notation for this notion.

Comment: I normally write $\ell^2(E)$;  for example $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$.  We understand this as $L^2(E,\mu)$ where $\mu$ is "counting measure".

Comment: @GEdgar I feel like I've seen $\ell^2(E)$ also used to denote the square summable sequences index by $\mathbb{N}$ who take values inside the set $E$. Is this notation more standard in a particular field, e.g. probability?

Answer (score 1):

A rather standard notation is one of the following: $L^2(E),$ $L^2(c_E)$ or $L^2(E, c_E),$ where $c_E$ is [counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure) on $E$. Since $E$ is countable, the expected measure is the counting measure; that's why it might be enough with $L^2(E).$ Anyway, I suggest that you explain the notation shortly when you introduce it.

Comment: I think I've seen $L^2(E)$ also used to denote the square integrable functions who are compactly supported on $E$, where $E$ is usually taken to be a subset of some other space. Are these two notions consistent?

Comment: For compactly supported functions it's common to use subscript $c$. An example is $C_c^\infty,$ the space of compactly supported and infinitely differentiable functions, which is used in distribution theory.